# Getting 200 status code with empty data in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

i am working with web api and MVC application.
When i run my application, able to see that my all services are running in my local iis

[image]

and my request is hitting the api anf getting 200 response back with empty data.

[image]

Hear dataservices in my web webconfig

```
<add key="dataservices" value="https://localhost:44333/" />
```

Same solution and same changes working in other system. i thought my iis is problem. i repair it also.

can any one help how can i fix

Comment: What is the problem here? Does the URL exists? What do you expect to see if the service is running?

Comment: Yes that Url is exists. That Url will return some data which i display in my web UI. Same solution is working fine in other system

Comment: So the url exists and it is returning data. Why do you expect it to NOT send 200 then?

Comment: it's not returning the data, that's my problem

Comment: Do you see some red error in your console output of the browser?

Comment: :) nothing in console output

Comment: you should just debug the action. If you can't debug it, add log traces.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for this issue.

Due to remote certificate issue my web is not returning response back.

[Remote certificate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure/)

Thanks you @stan and @fbiagi for your comments.